# Is istream::seekg with ios_base::end reliable?

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, io

Consider I created a file using this way:

```
std::ofstream osf("MyTextFile.txt");
string buffer="spam\neggs\n";
osf.write(buffer,buffer.length());
osf.close();
```

When I was trying to read that file using the following way, I realized that more characters than present was read.

```
std::ifstream is("MyTextFile.txt");
is.seekg (0, is.end);
int length = is.tellg();
is.seekg (0, is.beg);

char * buffer = new char [length];
is.read (buffer,length);

//work with buffer

delete[] buffer;
```

For example, if the file contains `spam\neggs\n`, then this procedure reads 12 characters instead of 10. The first 10 chars are `spam\neggs\n` as expected but there are 2 more, which have the integer value `65533`.
Moreover, this problem happens only when `\n` is present in the file. For example, there is no problem if file contains `spam\teggs\t` instead.

The question is;
Am I doing anything wrong? Or doesn't this procedure work as it should do?

Bonus Q: Can you suggest an alternative for reading the whole file at once?

Note: I found this way [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote the string

```
"spam\neggs\n"
```

initially to an `ofstream`, without setting the `std::ios::binary` flag at the `open` (or on the initializator). This causes the runtime to translate to the "native text format", i. e., to convert each `\n` to `\r\n` on the output (as you are on Windows OS). So, after being written, the contents of your file was actually:

```
"spam\r\neggs\r\n"
```

(i. e., 12 chars). *That* was returned by

```
int length = is.tellg();
```

But, when you tried to `read` 12 chars you got

```
"spam\neggs\n"
```

back, because the runtime converted each `\r\n` back to `\n`.

As a final advice, please, *please*, don't use `new char[length]`... use `std::string` and `reserve` so you won't leak memory etc. And if your file can be very big, maybe it's not a good idea to *slurp* the whole file to memory at once, also.

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea, since the number 2 corresponds to the count of `\n`s: Are you doing this on Windows? It might have something to do with the file actually containing `\r\n`. What happens if you open the file in binary mode (`std::ios::binary`)?

Comment: Yeah I am on windows but I do not write the endlines to file manually, instead I used `ostream` to write `spam\neggs\n` to file. I will check with binary mode too

Comment: @SweeneyTodd : If the `ostream` wasn't opened in binary mode then it added the `\r`s for you

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, that. I wanted to post but SO would not let me. `ofstream` without binary mode converts into the platform's native format.

Comment: ok, but still, what does it have to do with `is.seekg (0, is.end)`? That seekg function goes out of scope(to the 12th char) instead of 10th char, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but when you read the chars, it will convert each `\r\n` on the input file to `\n`, hence the ten chars. Recapitulating: you write `spam\neggs\n` to a non-binary `ofstream`, the contents of the file are `spam\r\neggs\r\n` (12 chars). That is returned by `tellg` when you reopen the same file with an non-binary `ifstream`. Then you read the contents, and it will read `spam\neggs\n` (because the `ifstream` is not binary). **ANYWAY**, if you just use `std::ios::binary` _both_ for reading _and_ writing, then you will not have that kind of problems anymore.

Comment: @Massa thankyouthankyou. if you write it as an answer, I will set it as accepted one

Answer (score 2):

> Can you suggest an alternative for reading the whole file at once?

Yes:

```
std::ifstream is("MyTextFile.txt");
std::string str( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{is}, {} ); // requires <iterator>
```

`str` now contains the file. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for showing an alternative way but what I really want to know is what is wrong with the way I used